# ggplot not colouring plots

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, plot

Recent user here. Was trying to plot toguether several numeric objects representing several environmental variables (each with average values for every month of the year) with ggplot. My goal was to get a combined dot plot, with the values of each variable in a different colour, nonetheless I get the plot in B/W. what I'm getting wrong? Thanks

my code:

```
EnvDF <- data.frame(variable = rep(c("CHL", "EZ", "NO3", "PHOS", "SSS", "SST"), each = 12),
                 month = rep(1:12, times = 6),
                 value = c(monthly_avCHL, monthly_avEZ, monthly_avNO3, monthly_avPHOS, monthly_avSSS, monthly_avSST))

ggplot(EnvDF, aes(x = month, y = value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.3)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "blue", "green", "orange", "purple", "pink")) +
  labs(x = "Month", y = "Average Value") +
  ggtitle("Enviromental av values") +
  theme_bw()
```

and this is what I get:

[Environmental plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGkAI.png)

Comment: By default, points only have a color, not a fill. So use `aes(....., color = variable)` and `scale_color_manual`.

Comment: The default point shape used by `geom_point` supports only the `color` aes, i.e. use `color= variable` and `scale_color_manual`. Alternatively switch to a shape which supports `fill`, e.g. `shape=21`, i.e. do `geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.3), shape=21)`.

Comment: Alternatively, use a point shape that _does_ have a fill, like `geom_point(...., shape = 21)`

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `fill` aesthetics which only applies to geometries whose area can actually be filled such as bars or densities.

For geometries that do not have an area, such as points and lines, the `color` aesthetic must be used.

Note that the scale function should be adapted as well: `scale_`***color***`_manual`.

```
ggplot(EnvDF, aes(x = month, y = value, color = variable)) +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.3)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "blue", "green", "orange", "purple", "pink")) +
  labs(x = "Month", y = "Average Value") +
  ggtitle("Enviromental av values") +
  theme_bw()
```